# Unknown component connected to white wire of rechargeable battery

Tags: battery-charging, thermistor

I want to replace a battery for a TDK A26 speaker. (You can see a picture of the battery [here](https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/QbEHCWfJbGr14HKn.huge)). In the country where I live it is no possible to find a replacement, so I decided to replace the individual batteries. However, there is a component I am not sure how to replace. At first glance, it seems a diode. I tried to test it using a multimeter but it is 'open'. I did attach another picture of the battery which shows the 'diode'. It is conected to a thermistor  jk-d175.

[image]

I found a video in Ytb  where they conect directly the white wire to the negative terminal, I was tempt to do the same but I am sure there are better alternatives.

I will apreciate any suggestion about how to replace that component.

Comment: Why do you want to replace it? How do you know it's defective if you don't know what it is or does?

Comment: @jsotola you can see the white wire in the image of the replacement, (You can see a picture of the battery:  https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/QbEHCWfJbGr14HKn.huge)

Comment: Very good point  @Transistor. I tested it like a diode. I expected to measure the typical 0.7 V of a diode or more if it was a zener diode

Comment: Christobol has the right answer. The component is a glass thermistor. The white component JK-D175 is not the thermistor, it is a PTC polymer fuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks pretty similar to [this](https://www.indiamart.com/proddetail/axial-leaded-glass-thermistor-7611420755.html), but no guarantees on the specs or anything.  You said you measured no continuity, but the ones on that page range from 5K to 100K; maybe you weren't on a high enough range to see it.  If this is what it is, they have a fairly low failure rate, at least from electrical stresses.

Comment: I did not test it as a resistor but you are correct. It is a resistor. I have never seen something similar, my experience is little. Thanks for sharing

Comment: It's probably a thermistor, it's used so a controller can monitor the battery temperature.  Warm it up a little and see if the resistance goes down.  The standard thermistor to use for batteries is 10K at 25C, but with a custom circuit you can use whatever value you want.